# Error Building Oreka

Tags: voip, autotools

I'm trying to build Oreka Voip recording platform on my CentOs server, but when i finally execute the command:

```
[root@localhost orkbasecxx]# make -f Makefile.cvs
```

I get the following:

```
aclocal
aclocal: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
autoheader
automake
automake: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
configure.in:4: warning: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE: two- and three-arguments forms are deprecated.  For more info, see:
configure.in:4: http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Modernize-AM_005fINIT_005fAUTOMAKE-invocation
configure.in:17: error: required file './config.guess' not found
configure.in:17:   'automake --add-missing' can install 'config.guess'
configure.in:17: error: required file './config.sub' not found
configure.in:17:   'automake --add-missing' can install 'config.sub'
configure.in:4: error: required file './install-sh' not found
configure.in:4:   'automake --add-missing' can install 'install-sh'
configure.in:4: error: required file './missing' not found
configure.in:4:   'automake --add-missing' can install 'missing'
automake: warning: autoconf input should be named 'configure.ac', not 'configure.in'
audiofile/Makefile.am:6: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
filters/audiogain/Makefile.am:5: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
filters/g722codec/Makefile.am:6: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
filters/g726codecs/Makefile.am:6: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
filters/g726codecs/g72x/Makefile.am:5: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
filters/gsm/Makefile.am:6: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
filters/gsm/gsm610/Makefile.am:8: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
filters/ilbc/Makefile.am:6: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
filters/ilbc/ilbc/Makefile.am:9: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
filters/speex/Makefile.am:6: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
messages/Makefile.am:9: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
serializers/Makefile.am:8: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I need help solving this.

Comment: It looks like you haven't run `automake -a`. Oreka's build steps are a bit fiddly, make sure to follow the docs at http://oreka.sourceforge.net/oreka-documentation.html

Answer (score 0):

In **Makefile.am** change

`INCLUDES = . . .`

to

`my_lib_name_CPPFLAGS = . . .`

Run `autoreconf -fi` and try again.